# Ocultar un <div> si en fullcalenar js no se obtiene un valor desde la base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, html, modal, fullcalendar

El siguiente código obtiene información de una base de datos y los almacena en una etiqueta  respectivo de un modal para luego mostrarlo en pantalla a través de fullcalendar:

```
eventClick:function(calEvent,jsEvent,view){
            $('#titulo').html(calEvent.title);
            FechaInicio = calEvent.start._i.split(" ");
            $('#fecha-inicio').html(FechaInicio[0]);
            $('#hora-inicio').html(FechaInicio[1]);
            FechaCierre = calEvent.end._i.split(" ");
            $('#fecha-cierre').html(FechaCierre[0]);
            $('#hora-cierre').html(FechaCierre[1]);
            $('#tipo').html(calEvent.Tipo);
            $('#lugar').html(calEvent.Lugar);
            $('#fecha-encuentro').html(calEvent.Fecha_encuentro);
            $('#hora-encuentro').html(calEvent.Hora_encuentro);
            $('#punto-encuentro').html(calEvent.Punto_encuentro);
            $('#material-individual').html(calEvent.Material_individual);
            $('#material-equipo').html(calEvent.Material_equipo);
            $('#ficha').html(calEvent.Ficha);
            $("#modal").modal();
        }
```

Después esta el código del modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <strong>Fecha inicio:</strong><div id="fecha-inicio"></div>
            <strong>Fecha cierre:</strong><div id="fecha-cierre"></div>
            <strong>Lugar:</strong><div id="lugar"></div>
            <strong>Fecha encuentro:</strong><div id="fecha-encuentro"></div>
            <strong>Punto encuentro:</strong><div id="punto-encuentro"></div>
            <strong>Material individual:</strong><div id="material-individual"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <strong>Hora inicio:</strong><div id="hora-inicio"></div>
            <strong>Hora cierre:</strong><div id="hora-cierre"></div>
            <strong>Tipo:</strong><div id="tipo"></div>
            <strong>Hora encuentro:</strong><div id="hora-encuentro"></div>
            <strong>Material equipo:</strong><div id="material-equipo"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Lo que quiero es que cuando en el javascript de fullcalendar alguno de los .HTML este vacío, entonces en el modal se oculte el  y el  en el modal, ya que no contiene ningún dato.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda para dar solución a este problema.

Comment: if(campo= ''){(div.style.display === "none"}

Comment: `if(calEvent.title && calEvent.title !="" ){$('#titulo').html(calEvent.title)};`O sea: si existe un titulo, utilízalo como html del elemento `#titulo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de varias soluciones posibles seria verificar si contiene informacion el campo, si contiene se pone el valor en el div, si no contiene valor se oculta el elemento, pero como esta separado la etiqueta strong del div con el valor seria conveiente meterlo todo en un div para ocultarlo todo junto, el codigo quedaria algo asi:

Codigo HTML

```
<style type="text/css">
  .hide{
       display: none;
    }
 </style>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div><strong>Fecha inicio:</strong><div id="fecha-inicio"></div></div>
        <div><strong>Fecha cierre:</strong><div id="fecha-cierre"></div></div>
        <div><strong>Lugar:</strong><div id="lugar"></div></div>
        <div><strong>Fecha encuentro:</strong><div id="fecha-encuentro"></div></div>
        <div><strong>Punto encuentro:</strong><div id="punto-encuentro"></div></div>
        <div><strong>Material individual:</strong><div id="material-individual"> </div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div><strong>Hora inicio:</strong><div id="hora-inicio"></div></div>
        <div><strong>Hora cierre:</strong><div id="hora-cierre"></div></div>
        <div><strong>Tipo:</strong><div id="tipo"></div></div>
        <div><strong>Hora encuentro:</strong><div id="hora-encuentro"></div></div>
        <div><strong>Material equipo:</strong><div id="material-equipo"></div></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui se crea una clase para poder ocultar el div mas comodamente, y en el javascript se realiza la validacion del valor con un ternario:

Codigo JS

```
eventClick:function(calEvent,jsEvent,view){
        calEvent.title ? $('#titulo').html(calEvent.title) : $('#titulo').parent().addClass('hide');
        FechaInicio = calEvent.start._i.split(" ");
        FechaInicio[0] ? $('#fecha-inicio').html(FechaInicio[0]) : $('#fecha-inicio').parent().addClass('hide');
        FechaInicio[1] ? $('#hora-inicio').html(FechaInicio[1]) : $('#hora-inicio').parent().addClass('hide');
        FechaCierre = calEvent.end._i.split(" ");
        FechaCierre[0] ? $('#fecha-cierre').html(FechaCierre[0]) : $('#fecha-cierre').parent().addClass('hide');
        FechaCierre[1] ? $('#hora-cierre').html(FechaCierre[1]) : $('#hora-cierre').parent().addClass('hide');
        calEvent.Tipo ? $('#tipo').html(calEvent.Tipo) :  $('#tipo').parent().addClass('hide');
        calEvent.Lugar ? $('#lugar').html(calEvent.Lugar) : $('#lugar').parent().addClass('hide');
        calEvent.Fecha_encuentro ? $('#fecha-encuentro').html(calEvent.Fecha_encuentro) : $('#fecha-encuentro').parent().addClass('hide');
        calEvent.Hora_encuentro ? $('#hora-encuentro').html(calEvent.Hora_encuentro) : $('#hora-encuentro').parent().addClass('hide');
        calEvent.Punto_encuentro ? $('#punto-encuentro').html(calEvent.Punto_encuentro) : $('#punto-encuentro').parent().addClass('hide');
        calEvent.Material_individual ? $('#material-individual').html(calEvent.Material_individual) : $('#material-individual').parent().addClass('hide');
        calEvent.Material_equipo ? $('#material-equipo').html(calEvent.Material_equipo) : $('#material-equipo').parent().addClass('hide');
        calEvent.Ficha ? $('#ficha').html(calEvent.Ficha) : $('#ficha')
        $("#modal").modal();
    }
```

O puedes usar un if si se te hace mejor:

```
        if(calEvent.title){
            $('#titulo').html(calEvent.title);
        } else{
            $('#titulo').parent().addClass('hide');
        }
```